# When can an exception in a .NET WinForms app just get eaten without being caught or bubbling up to a windows exception?

Tags: c#, winforms, unhandled-exception

In several places in our code, we notice that if running under debugger it'll show that there's an unhandled exception in the code, however if running outside the debugger it will just ignore the exception completely as if it were caught.  We have an exception handler that pops up an error submit dialog that's hooked up to Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
And neither of those appear to be catching them either.  We also log our exceptions and nothing appears in the log.

What are some possible reasons for this?

Edit: It seems that it isn't dependent on the type of exception throw, but rather where it is thrown.  This was tested by just adding:

```
throw new Exception("Test Exception");
```

It'll show up under debugger but doesn't show up outside, so in our case it's not a ThreadAbortedException or anything that's dependent on it being a specific type of exception.

Comment: Do you have a "catch all" exception handler such as: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnDomainExceptionThrown;

Comment: yes, that's mentioned in the question

Comment: I've got this happening as well.  I can get it to happen if I explicitly throw any sort of exception in my main form's Form_Load event handler.  In the debugger, it says it's unhandled, without the debugger, it just swallows it and moves on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one place where this could occur is if there's an exception in the UnhandledException event handler.  An easy way to see this is this:
In the Form.Load event handler throw any old exception.
In the Application.ThreadException event put something similar to the following:

```
static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
     string b = null;
     int i = b.Length;
}
```

Under debugger it'll show your exception was unhandled by user code, and then after that it'll show a null reference exception in the ThreadException handler, but if you run it outside the debugger it'll just swallow the exception like it was handled.

Comment: If you're able to catch it in the debugger, can you see what type of exception it is? And the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I can, but we have an error submit dialog for when our end users find bugs that we didn't, in which case only being able to catch them under debugger doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

There are some special exceptions that don't get bubbled up or caught, it sounds like you're dealing with one of them: see [ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to modify the properties of a Windows Form control from a different thread the control was created in, you get an [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(VS.80).aspx) if there is a debugger attached, but it gets silently ignored otherwise.

More info on the issue can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invoked from the framework.

Sometimes, the framework wraps its calls in an exception handler.

So, if there's an exception in your code, it may be (if there's an exception handler there in the framework) caught and ignored by the framework.

Maybe the debugger shows it as "unhandled" because, although there's a handler in the framework, there's no handler in your code? Or, because there's something strange about the handler in the framework, for example that it's an unmanaged, structured exception handler?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .Net 1.0/1.1? There was a huge change in behaviour in the transition from 1.1 to 2.0. Before then exceptions raised on threads you created or ThreadPool threads would be swallowed silently by the frameworok and the thread would exit. Thankfully this behaviour has now been fixed.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx):

> ### Change from Previous Versions
>
> The most significant change pertains
>   to managed threads. In the .NET
>   Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1, the
>   common language runtime provides a
>   backstop for unhandled exceptions in
>   the following situations:
>
> - There is no such thing as an unhandled
>     exception on a thread pool thread.
>     When a task throws an exception that
>     it does not handle, the runtime prints
>     the exception stack trace to the
>     console and then returns the thread to
>     the thread pool.
> - There is no such thing as an unhandled
>     exception on a thread created with the
>     Start method of the Thread class. When
>     code running on such a thread throws
>     an exception that it does not handle,
>     the runtime prints the exception stack
>     trace to the console and then
>     gracefully terminates the thread.
> - There is no such thing as an unhandled
>     exception on the finalizer thread.
>     When a finalizer throws an exception
>     that it does not handle, the runtime
>     prints the exception stack trace to
>     the console and then allows the
>     finalizer thread to resume running
>     finalizers.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a stretch here, but could it be that you just have set your debugger to break when an exception is thrown, and not only for the unhandled ones?